# Error cannot import name 'Seed' from 'iota'

Tags: pyota

When trying to import Seed from iota i receive following error:

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from iota import Seed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Seed' from 'iota' (C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\iota\__init__.py)
```

(compare to https://pyota.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#iota.Seed.random)

This is from a fresh python & pyota installation - Is this a known problem?

Thanks & regards, Gstar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Seed` was added to the top-level `iota` package in [PyOTA v2.2.0b1](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.py/releases/tag/2.2.0b1).

For earlier versions of PyOTA, use `from iota.crypto.types import Seed` instead.